# Should we have a tag for how chemicals achieve an effect without reacting?

Tags: discussion, tags

There already are tags here for [reaction-mechanism](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reaction-mechanism) but sometimes we might want to ask how an effect is achieved from a chemical that don't involve a chemical reaction.

For example, I just asked a question about Liquid crystals where the key issue was to understand how the chemical structures enable selective alteration of the polarisation of light when the orientation of the molecules is affected by a an electric field.

So I wanted to suggest a tag [mechanism](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanism) but that doesn't exist and, on reflection, is perhaps too general.

So what would be a good new tag for this sort of question? Should it be [physical-mechanism](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-mechanism) or [effect](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effect)? or something else?

Answer (score 3):

I see what you are saying here, but I don't think that your tags really add anything to the question.  If anything, a tag like [polarization](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polarization) might come into play to better support the specific situation.

Ultimately, when the site starts getting an increased number of visitors, people will start subscribing to more tags, and in that eventuality, it would be hard to find experts in a tag as vague as [effect](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effect).

Comment: OK, I agree some of my ideas were vague, but can we think of something better? would Physical-properties work?

Comment: @matt_black That's still a big vague, but I think that's the most livable out of all of the options.